# How do I move an object on the screen slowly?

Tags: c++, sfml

In my main game loop I am using the call `obj.move(1, 0)` to move an object to the right, but it moves really fast because it's in a loop. How can I slow it down to a certain speed?

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    // ...
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        object.move(1, 0);
}
```

Comment: The simplest but probably least optimal solution is to call a sleep function between frames. You should include a minimal example of your code so that a proper solution can be provided.

Comment: replace the `1` with `1.0 / deltaTime` if you want to keep a variable framerate.

Answer (score 2):

Measure the elapsed time (in milliseconds) for each frame, namely `delta`, and accumulate it in a variable that controls the animation (per object). Then wrap your `object.move` in a condition that checks whether its total elapsed time is greater than a certain amount, let's say, 30 milliseconds. This will cause approximatelly 33 moves per second - which looks like a smooth movement, not too quick, not too slow.

Comment: When do I stop checking the elapsed time to determine the value of delta?

Comment: The `delta` (or `dt`) is the amount of time spent on the _previous_ frame. You update it at the end of every frame, and also add it to `dt_accum` of every object you have interest in animating. When an object's `dt_accum >= 30`, move the object and do `dt_accum -= 30`, so that the object will only move when its `dt_accum >= 30` again. If you want to stop moving the object at some point, use a flag and/or stop updating its `dt_accum`.